# Is deletion a form of weighting?

Tags: weights

If observations are weighted in a regression model, is there are requirement that $w>0$ when calculating weights? It should be noted that some forms of weighted univariate statistics are special forms of regression like weighted (Horvitz-Thompson) mean and the kernal smoothed estimate of a probability density from a sample.

On one hand, when estimating weights there is a lot of discussion around estimators as general mathematical functions, and so setting the weight to 0 is a convenient way to describe trimming or outlier deletion. On the other hands, whether weights are interpreted as probabilities or frequencies, it seems pretty inconsistent to say a weight is 0 exactly.

Comment: Weighting what? Could you clarify?

Comment: @Tim in almost any sense really. I work mostly with regression, surveys, missing data.

Comment: Still, could you clarify? "Weights" is very broad and ambiguous term, e.g. many machine learning people would use "weights" for parameters and obviously there is no such requirement for parameters of regression, or neural network etc.

Comment: @Tim please see edit